# How to call a destructor with a casted pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, memory-leaks, destructor

This is a follow up question to [First Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944061/check-for-changes-in-pod-variables).

I have this class:

```
class Foo
{
     std::map<char**, char*> values;

public:
    ~Foo() { cleanAll(); }
    void cleanAll() {
        for(auto& value : values)
        {
            delete[] value.second;
        }
    }

    template<typename T> bool isChanged(T& entry)
    {
        char** addr = reinterpret_cast<char**>(&entry);
        auto it = values.find(addr);

        if(it == values.end())
        {
            char* oldBuf = new char[sizeof(T)];
            T* oldEntry = new(oldBuf) T;
            *oldEntry = entry;
            values[addr] = oldBuf;
        }
        else 
        {
            T* oldEntry = (reinterpret_cast<T*>(it->second));
            if(entry != *oldEntry)
            {
                oldEntry->~T();                  
                oldEntry = new(it->second) T;
                *oldEntry = entry;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

When I call this with an POD like `aFoo.isChange(aInt)` and the `aFoo` gets destroyed everything is ok. But when it's called with a complex type like `aFoo.isChange(aString)` and the `aFoo` gets destroyed there is memory leakage. I assume it's because the destructor doesn't know whats behind the `char*` inside the map and just calls the `char` destructor and not the one of the actual type it points to.

Is there a way to get rid of this memory leakage without changing the map `values`?

Comment: This is prone to fail miserably: `char** addr = reinterpret_cast<char**>(&entry);`

Comment: Why? It's just used as a key for the map. Nothing else.

Comment: At least I don't even have a clue why you're trying to use pointers as map keys. They won't work there as you might think they do.

Comment: Warning bells when people are using casts. Also make the destructor virtual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you try to process by considering all objects as a simple sequence of consecutive bytes, in order to monitor some changes on values.  I cannot judge if it's a good approach for the what you are intending to do, but it's obviusly a very risky approach.

**This code is doom to fail and is a real time bomb.**

First in `cleanAll()` you `delete[] value.second;`: this  will free the memory you have yourself allocated using `new[]char`.  But it will not safely delete the object if  a non trivial destructor is needed (such as for `string`) !  This means potentially memory leakage, but also other resources which might not be released correctly (e.g. files, threads, mutex, etc...).

Next, in your allocation of a new element:  `*oldEntry = entry;` is an assignment between `T` objects.  The trick with the poitner could make that the buffer you've allocated is copied using the appropriate copy assignment operator.  This means that the full semantic of the object copy is applied (for example, acclocating new memory, acquiring additional resources, or worse, altering the original object.

Now about the trick with the pointer:  you use here two pointers of different type to refer to the same memory location.  THis is [pointer aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) and might cause very subtle bugs due to the compiler's assumption that this should not happen.

Finnally, when you reassign an exising element in the map you correctly use a placement-new, first calling the destructor directly `oldEntry->~T();` and then crating the object at the location of the old one. Of course this works only if the type of the old and the new object is the same.

**Conclusion:**

At some moments you handle objects as a simple snapshot of their memory layout, and at some moments, you treat them with the full dignity of a living object with full semantic and side effects.

You could review your design, for example using a [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic) to safely manage a container with different types of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the response. I didn't liked this approach either. After spending some more work on the Problem I finally found a good solution. I posted it as an answer to my original question.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968539/1273855)